# What is the default join type and join order in direct query model?

Tags: powerbi

I have a direct query model with product dim and sales fact table.

The SQL profiler shows me the query does a LEFT JOIN from sales fact to product dim table.

1. What decides whether Power BI will do an INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN? Is this configurable?
2. In the case of LEFT JOIN, how does Power BI decide which table goes on the left side of the join? Is this configurable?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` by checking the "assume referential integrity" option in your relationship.  The table in the `LEFT JOIN` will be the table on the 1-side of the relation.

[Apply the Assume Referential Integrity setting in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-assume-referential-integrity)

Comment: `The table in the LEFT JOIN will be the table on the 1-side of the relation.` - so assuming dim to fact is 1:M relation, then the dim table will on left side?

Comment: I doubt that is the case because if fact table has a record without the matching dim key, then the blank is shown in the dimension visual - so I guess the left side should be the table in the M side?

Comment: Check this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-many-to-many-relationships#use-relationships-with-a-many-to-many-cardinality

Comment: The fact table is the `many` side and the dim table is the `1` side of the relationship - left or right, whichever way you define it doesn't matter.  If you turn on `assume referential integrity`, powerbi will use inner joins.  However, if you have integrity issues in the data, the results, like a missing dimensionkey, the results will be incorrect.